# VBS pass record count to a variable

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I would like to run the following VB Script and connect to some SQL server, and run the following query to count the number of rows. Then save that value to a variable, which I can use later.

What am I doing wrong??

```
Dim tempSQLCount 
tempSQLCount = 0

Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=someServer;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI"

Set sqlConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set sqlRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sqlConnection.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING 

Set sqlQuery = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" ) 
sqlQuery.ActiveConnection = sqlConnection 
sqlQuery.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB.dbo.Task" 
sqlQuery.Execute 

tempSQLCount = sqlRecordSet

Wscript.Echo sqlRecordSet

sqlRecordSet.Close
Set sqlRecordSet = nothing
sqlConnection.Close
Set sqlConnection = nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you've initialized the recordset with a value - You're just calling the execute method without saving the results.

Try:

```
sqlRecordSet.open sqlQuery
tempSQLCount = sqlRecordset.getRows()

Wscript.echo tempSQLCount(0,0)
```

Comment: ah, that's right. so inserted this after running the query command. I get a mismatch error when I echo the variable.

Comment: stretching my knowledge of the scripting objects, but why are you echoing the whole recordset? don't you just want to echo the "tempSQLCount"?

Comment: remember, .getRows() returns an array, so you need to specify which element in the array to echo: tempSQLCount(0,0)

Comment: sorry, pasted the wrong version of the code, but yes you are right, I want to echo the variable, not the RS.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a  while since I have used VBScript but maybe something like this...

```
Set sqlQuery = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" ) 
sqlQuery.ActiveConnection = sqlConnection 
sqlQuery.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) as Counter FROM DB.dbo.Task" 

Set sqlRecordSet = sqlQuery.Execute
sqlRecordSet.MoveFirst
tempSQLCount = sqlRecordSet("Counter")
```

Sorry I may be very rusty!